# Add time field to magento product

Tags: magento-1.8, product, product-attribute

How to get time field on product form I have attached screenshot what i want to do.[image]

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just add a simple text attribute and fill in what ever you want in it?

Comment: What about two time fields? from and to? What you want is not easy to achieve and either hard to parse or more work to show and change

Answer (score 1):

You can add one simple text attribute where you can enter the desired value.
If you need later to filter products based on start hour or end hour you can do as @FabianBlechschmidt suggests, and add 2 fields, one for start hour and one for end hour.
You can even go further and add 4 fields, 1 for starting hour, 1 for time of the day (AM or PM) then do the same and add 2 fields for closing hour.

Answer (score -1):

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product', 'register_time', array(
        'input' => 'time',
        'type' => 'time',
        'backend' => 'customer/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',       
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'required' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 51,
        'label' => 'Register Time',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'required' => 1,
        'comparable' => '0',
        'searchable' => '0',
        'visible_on_front' => 0, 
        'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
        'unique' => false,
        'note' => 'Time format is Hrs:Mins:Secs',
        'apply_to' => '', 
        'is_configurable' => false
    )
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I don't think there is such type as 'time'